# Does independence implies independence conditionally on max of the data?

Tags: probability, extreme-value, conditional-independence

Let be $X_1, ..., X_n$ I.I.D. numerical random variables with contiunous density $f$.
Note $M(X) = \max(X_1, ..., X_n)$ their maximum.

Are $X_1, ..., X_n$ independent conditionally on $M(X) = x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Not if the description of the problem is accurate.  As a hint: do you know anything about the value of $X_1$ if you know that $X_3, \dots, X_n < x$?  (Note the first subscripts $=3$!)  Does the conditional distribution of $X_1$ change depending upon what that first subscript is?

Comment: Consider the standard uniform case with $n=2$ and  $\Pr\{X_i \leqslant 0.99 x \vert M = x\}$.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, they are not independent.